# How to build a Framework class in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks

I want to build a framework regarding some common aspects used in xcode like that of UIKit, Foundation etc.  Is it possible for us to create our own framework which could be reused later ?  If so, could you tell us a step by step procedure of how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible, see:

https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

Comment: @rob5408, don't you mean "insanely great"? ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not currently possible to create a framework using the iPhone SDK.  The closest you can come is bundling the logic you want to have shareable into a static library.

This is a good writeup on how to go about doing that for the iPhone SDK:

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html